# Text span only renders after mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m building a webpage, HTML/CSS/JS
Im using dynamic script to render the page content.

There is a text section that won´t render totally until i hover it with the mouse.
[image]

The text missing is `<span class="product-shipping">` on all the 3 examples.

Any ideas would be helpfull!

**EDIT:** (**Got it working**) Added `position: relative;` to `title`
and added empty `<h3 id="title">` after the text.

```
.product-grid8 .title {
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 400;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   margin: 0 0 30px;
   transition: all .3s ease 0s;
   position: relative;
}
```

```css
h3.h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}


/********************* Shopping Demo-8 **********************/

.product-grid8 {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}

.product-grid8 .product-image8 {
  border: 1px solid #e4e9ef;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.product-grid8:hover .product-image8 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15)
}

.product-grid8 .product-image8 a {
  display: block
}

.product-grid8 .product-image8 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.product-grid8 .pic-1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-out 0s
}

.product-grid8:hover .pic-1 {
  opacity: 0
}

.product-grid8 .pic-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-out 0s
}

.product-grid8:hover .pic-2 {
  opacity: 1
}

.product-grid8 .social {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: 13px;
  z-index: 1
}

.product-grid8 .social li {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(3px);
  transition: all .5s ease 0s
}

.product-grid8:hover .social li {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0)
}

.product-grid8:hover .social li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: .1s
}

.product-grid8:hover .social li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: .2s
}

.product-grid8:hover .social li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: .4s
}

.product-grid8 .social li a {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: block;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out
}

.product-grid8 .social li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  border-color: #000
}

.product-grid8 .product-discount-label {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 15px 4px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(34% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(34% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%)
}

.product-grid8 .product-content {
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  color: white
}

.product-grid8 .price {
  color: #242424;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all .3s
}

.product-grid8 .price span {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  margin-left: 7px;
  display: inline-block
}

.product-grid8 .product-shipping {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  display: block;
  position: relative
}

.product-grid8 .title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.product-grid8 .title a {
  color: #000
}

.product-grid8 .title a:hover {
  color: #0081c2
}

.product-grid8 .all-deals {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2e353b;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 22px 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s
}

.product-grid8 .all-deals .icon {
  margin-left: 7px
}

.product-grid8 .all-deals:hover {
  background-color: #0081c2
}

@media only screen and (max-width:990px) {
  .product-grid8 {
    margin-bottom: 30px
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap" style="height: auto px;">
  <div class="row" id="main-content">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="guts">
      <h2 style="color: #242424">Test</h2>
      <br>

      <div class="container-ourdogs">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="product-grid8">
              <div class="product-image8">
                <a href="#">
                  <img class="pic-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/my30707/teste1.png">
                  <img class="pic-2" src="https://i.ibb.co/qWsDm3V/teste2.png">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-content">
                <div class="price">Rusty Viking
                </div>
                <span class="product-shipping">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a dictum purus, at tempus risus. Integer sapien nisl, pellentesque eu iaculis ut, luctus ac ligula. Praesent eu risus nunc.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="product-grid8">
              <div class="product-image8">
                <a href="#">
                  <img class="pic-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/my30707/teste1.png">
                  <img class="pic-2" src="https://i.ibb.co/qWsDm3V/teste2.png">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-content">
                <div class="price">Rusty Viking
                </div>
                <span class="product-shipping">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a dictum purus, at tempus risus. Integer sapien nisl, pellentesque eu iaculis ut, luctus ac ligula. Praesent eu risus nunc.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="product-grid8">
              <div class="product-image8">
                <a href="#">
                  <img class="pic-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/my30707/teste1.png">
                  <img class="pic-2" src="https://i.ibb.co/qWsDm3V/teste2.png">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-content">
                <div class="price">Rusty Viking
                </div>
                <span class="product-shipping">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a dictum purus, at tempus risus. Integer sapien nisl, pellentesque eu iaculis ut, luctus ac ligula. Praesent eu risus nunc.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do it in the next way. If text that toggle placed inside hover/mouseover trigger you might just wrote a simple css style. Something like this. Choose what you need display or visibility.

```
.parent:hover .child {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.child {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```